# Can we state "over the course of next six years"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Does this sentence read correctly? Please advise.

This implementation plan started in January 2014 and is scheduled to be rolled out worldwide over the course of next six years.

Thanks,
Mahi.

Answer (score 1):

Say: Over the course of *the* next six years.

Be advised, you are going to be asked to take this type of question to to the [English language learners stack exchange site.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Nope. ELL doesn't do proof-reading either.